# How to add an element to all objects in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects:

```
var data = [{"name":"albin"},{"name", "alvin"}];
```

How can I add an element to all the records?

I want to add `"age":"18"` to all the records:

```
[{"name":"albin", "age":"18"},{"name", "alvin", "age":"18"}];
```

Comment: `var data = [{"name":"albin"},{"name, "alvin"}];` is not a JSON, its an array

Comment: @FlyingGambit: `[{"name": "albin"}, {"name": "alvin"}]` is a valid JSON

Comment: @KarolKlepacki: JSON is a string format. What you have there is just a JavaScript array.

Comment: @KarolKlepacki It's not JSON. It's an array of objects. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `forEach` to iterate through the through this json array & add a key `age` to each of the object

```
var data = [{
  "name": "albin"
}, {
  "name": "alvin"
}];

data.forEach(function(item) {
  item.age = 18
});

console.log(data);
```

Note: The json in the question is not valid

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/owgunnew/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{"name": "albin"}, {"name": "alvin"}];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].age = "18";
}
```